# Send and Recive data as Array to API using FOSRestBundle

Tags: arrays, api, symfony, fosrestbundle, query-string

Hi I use FOSRestBundle to create my API.
I have to send data as ARRAY like:

```
"sender"=>array("name"=>"adm","city"=>"Rz")
```

and more.

I read documentation and I didn't know how to recive data array!

My function:

```
/**
     * @QueryParam(name="recipient", description="Page of the overview.")
     * @QueryParam(name="sender", description="Page of the overview.")
     *

     */
    public function putDispatchAction(ParamFetcher $params)
    {

//       $params =  $request;
        $rec = $params->get('recipient');
        $sender = $params->get('sender');
```

I try to recive parameter sender which is array()
But how?

I use symfony 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html) properly. I guess, you need to configure `View layer` and `Listener support` properly to interact with client via [json, xml]. TO start with use `json`. Then, you can pass the array as an `JSON` string which again can be decoded to array by client.

I used to get request data (GET, POST) from client via `Request`. It was again being transformed by `format_listener` to array / object.

Hope this helps!